# How do I customize the page footer in Gitbook?

Tags: gitbook

Is there a way to customize the per-page footer in [Gitbook](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook)? I want to add additional information beyond the name of the current section.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin for that on npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-layout

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. I'm also searching for a way to add a customized header to the gitbook.

Maybe you can make your own layout via ./localtheme at your gitbook.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me. But if the gitbook is updated there could be problems with it.
Also there are problems with some Linux Systems when building the book via shell